# What scale is initial bearing in returned from Location.distanceBetween()

Tags: android, gps, bearing

When calling Location.distanceBetween() and getting the initial and final bearing, what scale is the bearing in?  I'm getting negative values, which doesn't make sense to me.  Bearing goes from 0 to 360 degrees (relative or absolute, it doesn't matter).  The only thing I could think of is N through E through S is 0 through 180 degrees, and N through W through S is 0 through -180 degrees.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you already concluded:

In the function description, degrees East of true North are mentioned. True North is geographical, which somewhat differs from North determined via Earth magnetism (South magnetic pole).

So, if you are moving towards East, your bearing is 90 degrees, if you are moving towards South it is +180 or - 180, if you are moving towards West it is -90 degrees.

Comment: Odd.  I wonder why they didnt just stick with the standard 360 degree bearing thingy that, you know, the rest of the world uses.  All those years as a boy scout...wasted!

Comment: I understand your disappointment. But that's how the things are.

Comment: This answer is correct. And that turbo's comment is correct too.